# Labeling a GeoJSON with OpenLayers 5

Tags: openlayers, labeling, geodjango

I'm trying to put a label over a polygons. My polygons cames from a GeoJSON serialized by GeoDjango. I'm be able to categorize this polygons using the attribute *"type"* but I wanto to see the height as label. The height is inside the attribute *"height"*, then I've write this:

```
var strokeEdificiCasalnuovo = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)',
    lineDash: null,
    lineCap: 'butt',
    lineJoin: 'miter',
    width: 1,
});

var labelEdifici = function(feature) {
  return new ol.style.Text({
    textAlign: 'center',
    textBaseline: 'middle',
    font: '12px Verdana',
    text: function(feature) {
      var text = feature.get('height');
      return text;
      },
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'white', width: 0.5})
  });
};

var baracca = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: strokeEdificiCasalnuovo,
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(121,121,125,1.0)',
  }),
  text: labelEdifici,
});
.
.
.
.
var sourceEdificiCasalnuovo = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '{% url 'edificicasalnuovo_geojson' %}',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  });

var edifici_casalnuovo = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: '<p>Edificato</p>',
  source: sourceEdificiCasalnuovo,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
            if ( feature.get('type') == 'Baracca') {
              return [baracca];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Cabina di trasformazione') {
              return [cabinaTrasformazione];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Edificio del terziario industriale') {
              return [edificioTerzIndustriale];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Edificio di culto, cappella, campanile') {
              return [edificioCulto];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Edificio diroccato o rudere') {
              return [edificioDiroccato];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Edificio generico') {
              return [edificioGenerico];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Edificio in costruzione') {
              return [edificioCostruzione];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Edificio industriale') {
              return [edificioIndustriale];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Serra') {
              return [serra];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Tettoia o pensilina') {
              return [tettoia];  
            }
      }
});
```

With this in console I see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.getFill is not a function
    at e.setTextStyle (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at MultiPolygon (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at VM4026 ol.js:7
    at Ua (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at e.renderFeature (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at e.<anonymous> (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at e.prepareFrame (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at e.renderFrame (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at e.renderFrame_ (VM4026 ol.js:7)
    at e.<anonymous> (VM4026 ol.js:7)
```

What is wrong in my code? I'm not an expert of JavaScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `labelEdifici` defined as a function but `feature` is never being passed to it.  If you make it a constant you can set the text value in the style function where `feature` is passed

```
var labelEdifici = new ol.style.Text({
    textAlign: 'center',
    textBaseline: 'middle',
    font: '12px Verdana',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'white', width: 0.5})
  });

var baracca = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: strokeEdificiCasalnuovo,
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(121,121,125,1.0)',
  }),
  text: labelEdifici,
});


  style: function(feature, resolution) {
            if ( feature.get('type') == 'Baracca') {
              baracca.getText().setText(feature.get('height'));
              return [baracca];
            } else if (feature.get('type') == 'Cabina di trasformazione') {
```